# Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20

Tags: android, textview

I'm very new to android development. I know there are many questions like this in stack overflow. I referred those questions but I didn't get solution yet. Whenever I long press the `EditText` which is inside of `TextInputLayout` app getting crash.

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class TextView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:19805)
       at android.widget.Editor.getTextThumbnailBuilder(Editor.java:2112)
       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1014)
       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9240)
       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21142)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class TextView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:19805)
       at android.widget.Editor.getTextThumbnailBuilder(Editor.java:2112)
       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1014)
       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9240)
       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21142)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x285 "res/color/primary_text_material_light.xml" a=1 r=0x106010a}
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:447)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:738)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:60)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:56)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:19805)
       at android.widget.Editor.getTextThumbnailBuilder(Editor.java:2112)
       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1014)
       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9240)
       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21142)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by android.view.InflateException
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:782)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor (TypedArray.java:447)
android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:738)
android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:671)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_relative_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sign_in_bg"
    class = "com.fitficfitz.android.ui.login.SignInFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_5"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_20"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_20"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_10"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/more_session_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SIGN IN"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_30"
            />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/book_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/book_session_toolbar"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/social_sign_in_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_126"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_50">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/twitter_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="@dimen/weight_1"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/twitter_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/size_10"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/twitter"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:letterSpacing="@dimen/letter_spacing_040"
                android:text="@string/login_with_twitter"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_13"
                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/social_divider_view"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_126"
            android:alpha="0.2"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@color/grey_eff6fc"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/facebook_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="@dimen/weight_1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/facebook_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/size_10"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/facebook"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:letterSpacing="@dimen/letter_spacing_040"
                android:text="@string/login_in_with_facebook"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_13"
                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/social_horizontal_divider_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/social_sign_in_linear_layout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_50"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:background="@color/grey_eff6fc"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/username_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/social_horizontal_divider_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_20"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_28"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size_28"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/username"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_25"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/username_image_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/username_image_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/social_horizontal_divider_view">
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/username_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Email Address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_16"
            android:translationY="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_13"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/username_base_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/input_layout_username"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/input_layout_username"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:background="@color/grey_eff6fc"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_10"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/password_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username_base_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_30"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_20"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_28"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/size_28"
        android:src="@drawable/password"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_passwrod"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username_base_view"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/password_image_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/password_image_view">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_16"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_13"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/forgot_password_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/username_base_view"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/size_20"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size_20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_30"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/forgot_password"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/password_base_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/input_layout_passwrod"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/input_layout_passwrod"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:background="@color/grey_eff6fc"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        style="@style/EndButtonStyle"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_32"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_button"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/sign_in_button"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_text"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_a8a9ab"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_13"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_question_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_4"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_question"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_a8a9ab"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="@dimen/alpha_04"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*primary_text_material_light.xml code:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/primary_text_disabled_material_light"/>
    <item android:color="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"/>
</selector>
```

*style/TextLabel code:*

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Show the xml code.

Comment: Where is code for `primary_text_material_light.xml`?

Comment: @KNeerajLal I have shared the code. Check it please.

Comment: What is the Theme you are you are using?

Comment: I'm using AppTheme.

Comment: What is the parent?

Comment: parent is AppBaseTheme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123851/discussion-between-madhan-kumar-and-k-neeraj-lal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue after spending some hours. The issue is I have missed to add `textColorHighlight` in my `style` for `TextInputLayout`. So, I changed my `theme` from

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

to

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/grey_5f6971</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Thanks guys who are helping me in comment and answer section.

Answer (score 1):

It just basically means that it was not able to find `primary_text_material_light.xml` in your resources res/color.xml

Please paste your xml code to get detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

library android support 7 should add rightly.you should remove and add libray and then clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

@line number 20 android:id="@+id/backButton"..... .
In your java file do this **ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backButton);**
you might be typecasting R.id.backButton with some other view type

Comment: As I can see you must be typecasting R.id.backButton with TextView replace it with what I have written.